# OpenLayers: Combine multiple OGC filters

Tags: openlayers-2, ogc, filter

I have two *OGC* filters client side:

```
<ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo matchCase="true">
        <ogc:PropertyName>code</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>secret</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
</ogc:Filter>   

<ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
    <ogc:Intersects>
        <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
        <gml:Box xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
            <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">1298543.0367787,7107400.531374 1299312.4070614,7203464.9016567</gml:coordinates>
        </gml:Box>
    </ogc:Intersects>
</ogc:Filter>
```

I have both filters represented as strings and I want to combine them into one filter. I can see in the [documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Format/Filter-js.html#OpenLayers.Format.Filter.read) that OpenLayers can create a *Filter Object* from a string, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

**Am I doing something wrong and/or how should I do it?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To read a filter from a string should look something like:

```
var my_filter_xml, parser, xml;

parser = new OpenLayers.Format.Filter.v1_1_0 ();
xml = new OpenLayers.Format.XML();
my_filter_xml = '<ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo matchCase="true"><ogc:PropertyName>code</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>secret</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo></ogc:Filter>'; //your filter string

var x = xml.read(my_filter_xml).documentElement
var filter1 = parser.read(x);
console.log(filter1);
```

This should return you an OpenLayers.Filter object. Do this for both your filters so you have two filter objects.

Finally create a new "parent" filter (which can be AND, OR, etc.) which combines the two:

```
    var parent_filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.AND,
        filters: [filter1, filter2]
    });
```

Comment: It looks good, but it doesn't work for me. The first filter returns undefined by the `parser.read()` and the second returns `TypeError: filter.components is undefined` - in both cases the `xml.read` works fine.

Comment: @Chau - try with the v1_1_0 filter.

Comment: I already tried the v1_1_0 filter, which makes sense to use due to its builtin support for the GML tag (which is missing in the v1 filter). It still doesn't work, but the v1_0_0 filter does!!! I haven't debugged through the v1_1_0 filter to determine the problem though. Since the v1_0_0 filter inherits from GML2 and v1_1_0 from GML3, it might be a problem with my filters not complying to the GML3 standard.

Comment: @Chau - I did try the code above with a new build of OpenLayers (2.11), and it created a valid object for the first filter (after stripping whitespace). What error are you getting?

Comment: The problem is that the GML2 implementation supports the `gml:Box` element and the the GML3 doesn't. So even though the v1_1_0 filter finds a spacial component, it fails to parse it and cannot return the filter due to its contents never was created. I am using OL 2.10 until the 2.11 is released as the *stable* version. For me using the v1_0_0 is just fine :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
    <ogc:And>
        <ogc:Or>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo matchCase="true">
                <ogc:PropertyName>code</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>secret</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:Or>
        <ogc:Or>
            <ogc:Intersects>
                <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                <gml:Box xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
                    <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">1298543.0367787,7107400.531374 1299312.4070614,7203464.9016567</gml:coordinates>
                </gml:Box>
            </ogc:Intersects>
        </ogc:Or>
    </ogc:And>
</ogc:Filter>
```

**EDIT #1:** Here's my code in case it helps any :

```
MyApp.Search.GetWFSSpatialFilters = function () {

    function getOtherAttributesFilter() {
        var _filters = [];
        //If txtMyAppID has a value, add them.
        var MyAppIDs = $.trim($("#txtMyAppID").val()).split(",");

        if (MyAppIDs != "") {

            for (r in MyAppIDs) {
                _filters.push(
                    new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                        property: "id",
                        value: MyAppIDs[r]
                    })
                );
            }

        }

        return _filters;
    }

    function getDateFilter() {
        var _filters = [];
        //If startTime OR endTime fall between search times, it's a match.
        _filters.push(
            new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.BETWEEN,
                property: "startDate",
                lowerBoundary: MyApp.Util.ISODateString(MyApp.UI.ControlPanel.DateRange.getDateFrom()),
                upperBoundary: MyApp.Util.ISODateString(MyApp.UI.ControlPanel.DateRange.getDateTo())
            })
        );
        _filters.push(
            new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.BETWEEN,
                property: "endDate",
                lowerBoundary: MyApp.Util.ISODateString(MyApp.UI.ControlPanel.DateRange.getDateFrom()),
                upperBoundary: MyApp.Util.ISODateString(MyApp.UI.ControlPanel.DateRange.getDateTo())
            })
        );
        return _filters;
    }
    function getSatFilter() {
        var _filters = [];

        //gather all satellites 
        $.each(MyApp.Satellites.Items, function (index, satellite) {

            if (satellite.checked) {
                //console.log("(" + satellite.name.toString() + ")");

                _filters.push(
                    new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                        property: "platformName",
                        value: satellite.name.toString()
                    })
                );
            }
        });

        return _filters;
    }

    function getSpatialFilter() {
        var _filters = [];

        //console.log(MyApp.Region.Items);

        //if there aren't any regions defined, use viewport.
        if (MyApp.Region.Items.length > 0) {
            //gather all regions

            $.each(MyApp.Region.Items, function (index, region) {

                _filters.push(
                    new OpenLayers.Filter.Spatial({
                        //property: "boundsText",
                        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Spatial.INTERSECTS,
                        value: region.feature[0].geometry.clone().transform(MyApp.UI.Map.Projections.Mercator, MyApp.UI.Map.Projections.Geographic),
                        projection: "EPSG:4326"
                    })
                );

            });

        } else {
            // use viewport not to go over maxExtent.
            var boundsViewport = MyApp.UI.Map.getMap().getExtent().toGeometry().clone().transform(MyApp.UI.Map.Projections.Mercator, MyApp.UI.Map.Projections.Geographic).getBounds();
            var maxExtent = MyApp.UI.Map.getMap().maxExtent.toGeometry().clone().transform(MyApp.UI.Map.Projections.Mercator, MyApp.UI.Map.Projections.Geographic).getBounds();

            var geometryToUse;

            if (maxExtent.containsBounds(boundsViewport, false, true)) {
                geometryToUse = MyApp.UI.Map.getMap().getExtent().toGeometry().clone().transform(MyApp.UI.Map.Projections.Mercator, MyApp.UI.Map.Projections.Geographic);
            } else {
                geometryToUse = MyApp.UI.Map.getMap().maxExtent.toGeometry().clone().transform(MyApp.UI.Map.Projections.Mercator, MyApp.UI.Map.Projections.Geographic);
            }

            _filters.push(
                new OpenLayers.Filter.Spatial({
                    //property: "boundsText",
                    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Spatial.INTERSECTS,
                    value: geometryToUse,
                    projection: "EPSG:4326"
                })
            );

        }


        return _filters;
    }



    var _filters = [];


    //create sat filter.
    _filters.push(
        new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
            type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.OR,
            filters: getSatFilter()
        })
    );

    //create date filter.
    _filters.push(
        new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
            type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.OR,
            filters: getDateFilter()
        })
    );

    //create spatial filter.
    _filters.push(
        new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
            type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.OR,
            filters: getSpatialFilter()
        })
    );

    //create Other attributes filter.
    var attributefilter = getOtherAttributesFilter();
    if (attributefilter.length > 0) {
        _filters.push(
            new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
                type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.OR,
                filters: attributefilter
            })
        );
    }



    return _filters;
};


var searchFilter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.AND,
    filters: MyApp.Search.GetWFSSpatialFilters()
})

//console.log(myFilters);
var protocol = new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
    version: "1.1.0",
    url: MyApp.MapBase.Configuration.GeoServer.WFS_Service.EndPointURL,
    featurePrefix: MyApp.MapBase.Configuration.GeoServer.WFS_Service.featurePrefix,
    featureType: MyApp.MapBase.Configuration.GeoServer.WFS_Service.featureType,
    featureNS: MyApp.MapBase.Configuration.GeoServer.WFS_Service.featureNS,
    geometryName: MyApp.MapBase.Configuration.GeoServer.WFS_Service.geometryName,
    defaultFilter: searchFilter,
    srsName: MyApp.UI.Map.Projections.Mercator
});

var response = protocol.read({
    maxFeatures: MyApp.Search.Properties.maxResults,
    callback: MyApp.Search.SearchComplete_CallBack
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't that work without the Or tags too?

Comment: It could, but if he has an array of properties like "code" or geometries to intersect he's going to want to wrap them in the "Or" tag. Just wanna cover all bases.